# meta class with mutable data

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

From the search I have already done on the subject, I could only find one meta class that had constant values.

Is there any way of working with mutable meta class data?

Imagine if we were building a calculator through machine learning, and we have a database with tons of operations like 1098 + 1709 and than the meta class would be 2807, ...

... Is there any way of throwing values never seen before and getting a result that wasnt already set to be.

Answer (score 0):

I was using classification for predicting numbers, and that is a job of the regresion method.